# How to fetch data by column which is not in another class of @OneToMany unidirectional mapping in kotlin and Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

uni-directional mapping `fun findByPincode(pincode: Int) : List<Address>` is working fine as this is in my data class but when i am trying to fetch data by writing custom function like `fun findByCustomerId(customerId: Int) : List<Address>` is not working. I used to work in bi-direction mapping. Am i missing somthing here? My Data class, Repository and Controller are following.

```
@Entity
data class Customer(@Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long,
                    var firstName: String,
                    var lastName: String,
                    var phone: Long,
                    var email: String,
                    @OneToMany @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id") @Column(nullable = true) var address: List<Address>?)

@Entity
data class Address(@Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long,
                   var street: String,
                   var city: String,
                   var district: String,
                   var state: String,
                   var pincode: Int)
```

```
interface AddressRepository: JpaRepository<Address, Long> {

    fun findByPincode(pincode: Int) : List<Address>
    fun findByCustomerId(customerId: Int) : List<Address>// This Line is causing following error
}
```

```
@RestController
class CustomerController(@Autowired private val customerRepository: CustomerRepository) {
    @GetMapping("/api/v1/customers")
    fun getCustomers() = customerRepository.findAll()

    @PostMapping("/api/v1/customers")
    fun saveCustomer(@RequestBody customer: Customer) = customerRepository.save(customer)
}
```

When i am adding above line i am getting following error

```
Error creating bean with name 'addressRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.repository.AddressRepository.findByCustomerId(int)! No property customerId found for type Address!
```

Address Controller

```
@RestController
class AddressController(@Autowired private var addressRepository: AddressRepository) {

    @GetMapping("/api/v1/{cid}/address")
    fun getAddressByUserId(@PathVariable cid: Int) = addressRepository.findByPincode(cid)

}
```

Edit 1: **Working Code**
But is it possible to do from single side mapping ??

```
@Entity
data class Customer(@Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long,
                    var firstName: String,
                    var lastName: String,
                    var phone: Long,
                    var email: String,
                    @OneToMany @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id") @Column(nullable = true) var address: List<Address>?)

@Entity
data class Address(@Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long,
                   var street: String,
                   var city: String,
                   var district: String,
                   var state: String,
                   var pincode: Int,
                   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) @JsonIgnore var customer: Customer)
```

There seems to be only one way of working that is both way mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error creating bean with name 'addressRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.repository.AddressRepository.findByCustomerId(int)! No property customerId found for type Address!

The *PROBLEM* is that there is no such property as `customerId` in the Address Entity class and you are defining the repository method as `findByCustomerId`.

```
@Entity
data class Address(@Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long,
               var street: String,
               var city: String,
               var district: String,
               var state: String,
               var pincode: Int)
```

Try with putting `cusotmerId` field in the Address Entity and map with Customer Entity that should resolve your issue and notice that you have `pincode` field and you are not having an issue while defining the repository method for that.

```
@Entity
data class Address(@Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long,
               var street: String,
               var city: String,
               var district: String,
               var state: String,
               var pincode: Int,
               @Column(name = "customer_id") var customerId: Int)
```

Comment: hello i guess i am not able to properly explain.

I am trying to fetch data when i have uni-directional mapping. Means The mapping i was earlier doing was in both entity class i use to add mapping annotation and from another class i have to put @JsonIgnore this time i tried with one side.

Comment: Mapping with customer entity will make it bi-direction mapping and it will coz chaining in json result.

Comment: I am getting following error nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table [address] contains physical column name [customer_id] referred to by multiple logical column names: [customer_id], [customerId] WHEN I AM ADDING in address class var customerId: Int. May i need to add class and do the binding annotation from both side?

Comment: @VIKASROY There is no-way to make repository method doable unless you define that variable explicitly. I think you should add a field `customerId` in your Address Entity like `@Column(name = "costumer_id") var costomerId: Int` - which means you shouldn't have to define Customer class itself and that should *AVOID* the json chaining.

Comment: But that will create two customer_id column in database.

Comment: `@OneToMany @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id") @Column(nullable = true) var address: List<Address>?` seeing this code from Customer entity - I assumed that It should have already been created(without creating the duplicate one)

Comment: nope i am doing spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create not update for testing purpose

Comment: https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-mapping-example/

Comment: Oh! I see .... maybe it's worth changing ddl-auto type to *create-drop* to test/see the expected result... :)